# How to call a constant in 'plugins' block in a build.gradle.kts file?

Tags: gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I have the following file `Versions.kt`, which contains this:

```
package org.kopi.galite.gradle

object Versions {
  const val SPRING_BOOT = "2.7.14"
}
```

I have the following file `build.gradle.kts`, which contains this:

```
import org.kopi.galite.gradle.Versions

plugins {
  kotlin("jvm") apply true
  id("org.springframework.boot") version Versions.SPRING_BOOT
}
```

When I try to build my project, I get the following error:

```
Unresolved reference: Versions in build.gradle.kts
```

I would like to keep my structure like this, i.e., having one file that contains the versions of the different frameworks and dependencies, and calling them, instead of hard-coding the versions in the build.gradle.kts files.

Calling `Versions.SPRING_BOOT` outside of the `plugins` block does not generate any type of errors, and works completely fine. However, calling `Versions.SPRING_BOOT` inside the `plugins` block generates the above error for some reason.

What could I do to be able to use my constant `SPRING_BOOT` in the plugins block in my `build.gradle.kts` file?

Note that I am using Gradle 7.0 with Kotlin DSL.

Answer (score 0):

Not possible as indicated [here](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/issues/802#issuecomment-377613656) and [here](https://github.com/gradle/kotlin-dsl-samples/issues/158#issuecomment-358374735).

What you are describing is exactly what a [version catalog](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html#sub:version-catalog) is for. Your catalog could be:

```
[versions]
springBoot = "2.7.14"

[plugins]
springBoot = { id = "org.springframework.boot", version.ref = "springBoot" }
```

Which can then be used as:

```
plugins {
    alias(libs.plugins.springBoot)
}
```